# What are the restrictions on fast enumeration?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, fast-enumeration

Please correct me if I am wrong.

If we use fast enumeration:

```
NSMutableDictionary
```

We can't add/remove new entries, but we could change existing entries.

```
NSMutableArray
```

We can't add/remove new entries, but we could change existing entries.

```
NSMutableSet
```

We can't add/remove new entries or change existing entries.

Answer (score 0):

`NSDictionary`, `NSArray` or `NSSet` are finally non mutable object these can never be changed. 
You can change the object in these classes.

When using fast enumeration, or any type of enumeration you should always watch out when change the collect/array because the count change and can have weird and unintended results.

Comment: sorry, I am using mutable collections